# jquery как заменить hover на click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, меню

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#menu").hover(
          function () {
              $('#hide').show(); // #hide = display:none;
          },
          function () {
              $('#hide').hide();
          }
      );
  });
```

Если просто написать $("#menu").click или $("#menu").onClick то ничего не происходит.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, if toggle -> пропадают картинки <a id='menu'><img></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил все чистым JS`ом!
Непонятно, для чего придумали jquery.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

В html пишите так:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">
<div id="foo">This is foo</div>
```

Comment: JQuery упрощает работу, друг мой :)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#menu").click(function() {
    $('#hide').toggle()
  });
});
```

Comment: Нужно, что бы при включении кнопки другие включенные кнопки выключались. И привязать кнопку закрытия id="close" (которая в окне, которое меняет display с none на block).

Comment: @ALPHA, какой у вас класс у кнопок? Вы хотите, что бы при нажатии один блок открывался, а другие скрывались?

Comment: <a id='menu'><img></a> - несколько таких ссылок-кнопок, при клике на ссылку "#", js меняет display none на block блока который описан выше.

Comment: @ALPHA, ну? При клике на `#menu` будет открываться/скрываться блок

Comment: другие окна тоже открываются и прерыдущие не закрываются.

Comment: @ALPHA, покажите ваш HTML. Id должен быть уникальным. Нельзя использовать один и тот же id несколько раз

Comment: id уникальный, html не покажу)

Comment: @ALPHA, тогда разбирайтесь сами. Скрывайте остальные элементы с помощью display: none

Comment: @ALPHA, по идее решение в данном ответе подходит, только вместо ID использовать CSS класс -  $('.hide').toggle();. Тогда у каждой кнопки должен быть этот класс, и у всех кроме одной - display: none;

Answer (score -1):

Так?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#menu").on('click', function() {
          function () {
              $('#hide').show(); // #hide = display:none;
          },
          function () {
              $('#hide').hide();
          }
      });
  });
```

Это если соответствовать самому вопросу. Наведение заменил на клик, если вы хотите создать именно замену состояния, то нужен toggle как сказали другие комментаторы.

Comment: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Comment: @ALPHA вашу проблему решил пользователь "Yuri"? Если да - отметьте его ответ как правильный, если нет обьясните, пожалуйста, еще раз что вы хотите получить в результате работы скрипта. Я просто показал как назначать обработчики через определенные ивенты, но ваш код(который я попросту взял с вашего вопроса) неверный, потому скрипт в любом случае работать не будет, пока ваш код не будет исправлен. Вы написали в теме вопроса "как заменить hover на click", но похоже что ваша функция сама по себе неверна и потому вопрос нужно переформулировать.